# AngularJs preview on Facebook Share

Tags: angularjs, facebook, seo

I'm developing an AngularJs single page app and have run into an expected problem that I'm not sure how to solve. I had heard that both Google and Bing had changed how their crawlers worked and that they now execute Javascript. This, I hear, enables Angular based sites to be properly indexed by the search engines. The issue I'm having is when I go to share my page on Facebook the only part of my pages that the scraper is getting is the title (since it requires no Javascript, I assume).

I worry that social networks aren't going to work properly and search engines besides Google and Bing. Is this concern founded? What is the usual approach to resolving this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There's some considerable amount of work involved, but it can be done, given that you have clean JS.

There's a great tutorial here: http://yearofmoo.com/2012/11/angularjs-and-seo.html